# Как определить конец цикла в двух местах?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Есть такой код

```
<?php $volume = 0; ?>    
<?php foreach ($tpl_dat['col']['mng_chp'] as $key => $chp) { ?>
        <?php if ($volume != $chp['vol']) { ?>
 <li>
            <h3 class="vol">
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-<?php echo $chp['vol']; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vol-<?php echo $chp['vol']; ?>">Том <?php echo $chp['vol']; ?></a>
            </h3>
                <ul class="chp_lst lst collapse" id="vol-<?php echo $chp['vol']; ?>">
            <?php $volume = $chp['vol']; ?>
        <?php } ?>
<li id="chp-<?php echo $chp['slg']; ?>">
            Глава <?php echo $chp['slg']; ?>
          </li>
<?php } ?>
```

При выполнения получаем примерно такой вид

```html
<li>
  <h3 class="vol">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vol-3">Том 3</a>
            </h3>
  <ul class="chp_lst lst collapse" id="vol-3">
    <li id="chp-6">
      Глава 6
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="vol">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vol-2">Том 2</a>
            </h3>
      <ul class="chp_lst lst collapse" id="vol-2">
        <li id="chp-5">
          Глава 5
        </li>
        <li id="chp-4">
          Глава 4
        </li>
        <li id="chp-3">
          Глава 3
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3 class="vol">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vol-1">Том 1</a>
            </h3>
          <ul class="chp_lst lst collapse" id="vol-1">
            <li id="chp-2">
              Глава 2
            </li>
            <li id="chp-1">
              Глава 1
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Нужно в последнем томе вместо

```
<h3 class="vol">
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vol-3">Том 3</a>
</h3>
<ul class="chp_lst lst collapse" id="vol-3">
```

было

```
<h3 class="vol">
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="vol-3" class="">Том 3</a>
</h3>
<ul class="chp_lst lst collapse in" id="vol-3" aria-expanded="true">
```

И в конце каждого тома нужно поставить закрывающиеся теги

```
</ul>
</li>
```

Пример как должно быть

```html
<li>
        <h3 class="vol">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="vol-3" class="">Том 3</a>
        </h3>
                <ul class="chp_lst lst collapse in" id="vol-3" aria-expanded="true">
    
        <li id="chp-6">
            Глава 6
        </li>
         </ul>
</li>
<li>
 
        <h3 class="vol">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vol-2">Том 2</a>
        </h3>
                <ul class="chp_lst lst collapse" id="vol-2">
         <li id="chp-5">
            Глава 5
        </li>
        <li id="chp-4">
            Глава 4 
        </li>
    
        <li id="chp-3">
            Глава 3
        </li>
         </ul>
</li>
<li>
        <h3 class="vol">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#vol-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vol-1">Том 1</a>
        </h3>
    <ul class="chp_lst lst collapse" id="vol-1">
 
        <li id="chp-2">
            Глава 2
        </li>
 
        <li id="chp-1">
            Глава 1
        </li>
         </ul>
</li>
```

Как нужно изменить код в цикле, что бы получить нужный результат?

Comment: А вы можете оставить в вопросе суть, вылив всю воду?

Comment: Пытался наглядно показать то что хотел добиться...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Трудно вас понять, но попробую:

Вы можете определить особый вид последнего элемента через CSS :last-child.
В PHP понять, что текущяя итерация цикла последняя можно сравнивая индекс $key с заранее вычисленным значением.
Чтобы закрыть теги, просто напишите вывод закрывающих тегов после цикла.

**EDITED**:
Есть такой приём для вывода групп элементов: сначала собираем массив с ключём, зависящим от группы. Затем делаем двойной цикл группы-элементы чтобы вывести всё.

Псевдокод:

```
$volumes = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $volumes[$item['vol_id']][] = $item;
}
foreach ($volumes as $vol_id => $volume) {
  echo "<h2 id='vol-{$vol_id}'>{$volume[0]['vol_name']}</h2>\n";
  echo "<ul>\n";
  foreach ($volume as $item) {
    echo "  <li>{$item['item_name']}</li>\n";
  }
  echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

См.

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp
- http://php.net/manual/ru/function.end.php#68052
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5150297/272885

Comment: Мне нужно что бы теги </ul></li> были в конце у каждого тома... если в конце цикла их поставить то они не у каждого тома буду а в самом конце.

Comment: Ok. Дополню свой ответ примером.